# accessing the parts of a composite class

Tags: oop, encapsulation, pseudocode, composition

I am somehow confused with the concept of composition and encapsulation.

Here is the example which helps my bottleneck :
I have a class A, which has parts of types B and C. B has also parts of types D and E.

```
class A
{
   B itsB;
   C itsC;
}

class B
{
   D itsD;
   E itsE;
}

class D
{
   int mAlpha;
   int getAlpha();
   void setAplha(int);
}

A itsA;
```

For this case, how do you read-only access mAlpha ?

This way ? `itsA->getItsB()->getItsD()->getAlpha()`

or this way ? `itsA->getAlpha()`, where `A::getAlpha()` accesses `itsB->getItsD()->getAlpha()`

What about the way to write access mAlpha ?

This way ? `itsA->getItsB()->getItsD()->setAlpha(10.0)`

or this way ? `itsA->getItsB()->setAlpha(10.0)`, where `A::getAlpha()` accesses `itsB->getItsD()->setAlpha(10.0)`

So the question is ; to access/modify the parts of a composite class, while obeying the encapsulation principle, should you access only via the composite class' interface ?

Otherwise, it seems that you access the part, modify it, without the knowledge/permission of the owner composite.

Please help me to get rid of this confusion

Thanks.

Comment: Concerning your chained calls, have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So the question is ; to access/modify the parts of a composite class, while obeying the encapsulation principle, should you access only via the composite class' interface ?

According to the encapsulation principle, the composite's parts should be hidden. Assuming that `mAlpha` is logically a *property of* `A`, but *implemented in* `D`, you should add accessor methods in `A` that look up/change the `mAlpha` member in its `D` part. Otherwise, you'd be leaking implementation details of `A` (that it is a composite of a `D` and some other stuff).

Answer (score 0):

I would let `A` delegate the access to `getAlpha()` by exposing itself the same method name and signature.

```
class A
{
public:
    int getAlpha()
    {
        return itsB.getAlpha();
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    int getAlpha()
    {
        return itsD.getAlpha();
    }
};
```

Though this is complexifying your code, you should consider changing the way you encapsulate responsibilities.

Answer (score 0):

> For this case, how do you read-only access mAlpha ?
>
> This way ? itsA->getItsB()->getItsD()->getAlpha()
>
> or this way ? itsA->getAlpha(), where A::getAlpha() accesses itsB->getItsD()->getAlpha()

It's a little complicated since you have to respect both levels of encapsulation.
Presumably, B is used like a mix-in to implement A, so you might want B to be a private member of A, eliminating the possibility of the first method. The second ways hides the existence of B within A, and allows from some contracts to be implemented in A regarding what it will allow to be done to its B. You could layer the same sort of thing between B and D where you don't just serve up a pointer to D and grab the Alpha view, but use D privately in the implementation of B. You do end up with layers of methods calling each other, and in simple cases it seems inefficient, but it's about what a client of A knows about it's implementation, and what a client of B knows about B's implementation.

From that angle of thought, your first line is written so that a consumer of A must know it's internal structure to get to the Alpha value. It must know there is B in there with a D that has Alpha. To allow for changes in the implementation of A, you would hide that detail behind a function like getAlpha(). Then the same sort of thing for B.

HTH

-Chris

Answer (score 0):

I take "encapsulation" more as a general concept. A class has several fields, properties, methods, that are considered as a single item, wheter those members are public, private or protected. For "encapsulation", it doesn't matter if the object has other objects or not as members.

```
class CarClass {
  private: double InitialPrice;
  protected: WheelClass wheels[4];
  protected: MotorClass motor;
  public: turnOn();
  public: turnOff();
}
```

Here, "encapsulation" means, lets take this fields, wheter simple data types or objects, this methods, and put them all togheter into an entity.

For "composite class" or "composite object", I take it as an object, that has other objects as part of it. The class or object is responsible for creating or destroying those subelement objects. If a class has pointers or reference to other objects, but its not responsible of deleting or adding them (allocating in memory), then its not composite.

```
class SpaceShipClass {

  SpaceShipClass() {
   this.engine = new EngineClass();
   this.wings  = new WingClass();
  } 

  ~SpaceShipClass() {
   free this.engine();
   free this.wings();
  } 

  private: EngineClass engine; 
  protected: WingsClass wings; 
  public: PilotClass pilot; 

  public: Fly(); 
  public: Landing(); 
}
```

In the previous example, "engine" & "wings" make "SpaceShipClass" a composite class. But, the field "pilot", doesn't because it's doesn't "belong" to the class, it just has a reference.

Check that I'm not using a class member scope (private, protected or public) as something related to the "encapsulation" or "composition" concepts, it part of O.O.P., but its not need it for encapsulation or composition. In fact, there are O.O. Programming languages where all members are public, and still can have encapsulation or composie classes.

Programming languages with "references", makes more difficult to beginners to understand "class composition".